# "target_link_directories called with invalid arguments" when linking to ExternalProject built libs

Tags: cmake

CMake project building external libs:

```
include(ExternalProject)

set(EXTLIBS_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extlibs)

ExternalProject_Add(ext-somelib
    URL https://github.com/.../archive/refs/tags/somelib.tar.gz
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTLIBS_INSTALL_PREFIX}
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${EXTLIBS_INSTALL_PREFIX}
)

include_directories(${EXTLIBS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)

add_executable(mainTarget ...)

add_dependencies(mainTarget ext-somelib)

target_link_directories(mainTarget ${EXTLIBS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
target_link_libraries(mainTarget somelib)
# (link <build>/extlibs/lib/libsomelib.so)
```

when configuring the project it fails with the error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:# (target_link_directories):

> target_link_directories called with invalid arguments

What's the correct way to specify link directories for a dependency built with ExternalProject (hence not yet available at configure time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In command `target_link_directories` one of keywords PUBLIC, PRIVATE or INTERFACE is required.

Correct:

```
target_link_directories(mainTarget PRIVATE ${EXTLIBS_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

Comment: oops, I incorrectly assumed the error was about the missing directory